"Dagger Hilt: @Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type error"
I'm working on a Dagger Hilt setup in my Android project and encountered an error when using @Binds methods.
The error message is:
error: @Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type public abstract kotlin.time.TimeSource bindTimeSource(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
Here is my AppModule code:
package com.viswa.befocused.di


@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class AppModule {
    companion object {
        @Provides
        fun provideFocusedStatisticsDao(db: FocusedDatabase): FocusedStatisticsDao =
            db.focusedStatisticsDao()

        @Singleton
        @Provides
        fun provideDatabase(
            app: Application,
            callback: FocusedDatabase.Callback,
        ): FocusedDatabase =
            Room.databaseBuilder(app, FocusedDatabase::class.java, "focused_database")
                .addCallback(callback)
                .build()

        @ApplicationScope
        @Singleton
        @Provides
        fun provideApplicationScope(): CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())

        @MainDispatcher
        @Singleton
        @Provides
        fun provideMainDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main

        @Provides
        fun provideTimeSourceAdapter(defaultTimeSource: DefaultTimeSource): TimeSourceAdapter {
            return TimeSourceAdapter(defaultTimeSource)
        }
    }

    @Binds
    @JvmSuppressWildcards
    abstract fun bindTimeSource(timeSourceAdapter: TimeSourceAdapter): TimeSource

    @Binds
    @JvmSuppressWildcards
    abstract fun bindPreferencesManager(preferencesManager: DefaultPreferencesManager): PreferencesManager

    @Binds
    @JvmSuppressWildcards
    abstract fun bindPomodoroTimerStateManager(focusedTimerManager: DefaultFocusedTimerStateManager): FocusedTimerStateManager

    @Binds
    @JvmSuppressWildcards
    abstract fun bindTimerServiceManager(timerServiceManager: DefaultTimerServiceManager): TimerServiceManager

    @Binds
    @JvmSuppressWildcards
    abstract fun bindNotificationHelper(notificationHelper: DefaultNotificationHelper): NotificationHelper
}

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
annotation class ApplicationScope

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
annotation class MainDispatcher

I'm using:

Kotlin version: 1.9.0
Dagger Hilt version: 2.51.1

The DefaultTimeSource class does not directly implement kotlin.time.TimeSource,
code :
package com.viswa.befocused.feature.timer

import android.os.SystemClock
import javax.inject.Inject

class DefaultTimeSource @Inject constructor() : TimeSource {
    override val elapsedRealTime: Long
        get() = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
}

Code : Focused Database
@Database(
    entities = [PomodoroStatistic::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = true
)
abstract class FocusedDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun focusedStatisticsDao(): FocusedStatisticsDao

    class Callback @Inject constructor(
        private val database: Provider<FocusedDatabase>,
        @ApplicationScope private val applicationScope: CoroutineScope,
    ) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)
        }
    }
}

Code: FocusedStatisticDao
@Dao
interface FocusedStatisticsDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM focused_statistics ORDER BY timestampInMilliseconds")
    fun getAllPomodoroStatistics(): Flow<List<PomodoroStatistic>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertPomodoroStatistics(pomodoroStatistic: PomodoroStatistic)

    @Query("DELETE FROM focused_statistics")
    suspend fun deleteAllPomodoroStatistics()

}

Detailed Error
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\agent\StudioProjects\BeFocused
 
C:\Users\agent\StudioProjects\BeFocused\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\viswa\befocused\data\db\FocusedDatabase.java:12: warning: Schema export directory was not provided to the annotation processor so Room cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument by applying the Room Gradle plugin (id 'androidx.room') OR set exportSchema to false.
public abstract class FocusedDatabase extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase {
                ^
C:\Users\agent\StudioProjects\BeFocused\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\viswa\befocused\di\AppModule.java:41: error: @Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type
    public abstract kotlin.time.TimeSource bindTimeSource(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
                                           ^
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction

I have tried adding @JvmSuppressWildcards to the @Binds methods but still face the same issue.
Any guidance on how to resolve this type assignment issue with Dagger Hilt would be greatly appreciated.

The error message suggests that TimeSourceAdapter  does not implement the TimeSource interface, hence you are not allowed to bind it as such. If that doesn't help, please add your TimeSourceAdapter implementation to the question

@AdrianK interface TimeSource {
val elapsedRealTime: Long
} I don't have any TimeSourceAdapter

@AdrianK let me provide my github repo link

The AppModule  in your question (which btw is different from the one on github) does reference TimeSourceAdapter

@AdrianK how do i fix it
